# How to ask Varnish to answer from cache, without go to backend

Tags: varnish

Usually I request a file through a Varnish proxy, it returns a response from the cache, or accesses the backend for this.
Is there any way to request file from cache, or get 404 without forcing the Varnish to access the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following test case shows a possible approach:

```
varnishtest "..."

server s1 {
    rxreq
    txresp -hdr "Cache-Control: s-maxage=60"
} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    sub vcl_miss {
        if (!req.http.X-Warm-Cache) {
            return (synth(404));
        }
    }
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/foo" -hdr "X-Warm-Cache: 1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200

    txreq -url "/foo"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200

    txreq -url "/bar"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 404
} -run
```